# Jenkins: How to send mail with details of all the jobs ran in past one week

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement to send weekly report about all the jobs that ran on the Jenkins. Is there any feature/plugins available in Jenkins to perform this? Also, is it possible to generate this report by using shell script so that we don't need to install any plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Global Build Stats Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin). As the documentation states:

> Global build stats plugin will allow to gather and display global build result statistics. It is a useful tool allowing to display global jenkins/hudson build trend over time.

I think it fits to your requirements and it has a REST API where you can get the data you need for further processing. I don't know about any shell script solutions.

Comment: thanks @JGK. I am able to install the plugins and can see the graphs.